# Adding Char. Count And Limitation To Blog Entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, blogs, character

I am creating a Blog using RoR with a sign-in feature and I want to limit each article submission to say 1,000 characters and anyone's responding comments to 350 max. How would I implement or even start this?

Ideally the char count will count down when a char is added and change color when in the minus numbers (like Twitter).

or,

The article or comment throws up a flash notification if the user goes over the limit.

Am thinking that I can actually limit the char count adding the following in the model:

validates_length_of :article, :maximum => 800

validates_length_of :comment, :maximum => 400

Its the method of showing the user the remaining char count as they type, but on the client side for now? Can RoR do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validations you are asking, are very simple.
I would suggest you to implement them at the client side in the browser using javascript, jquery or any other js framework of your choice.

If you do the validations at the server side, in Rails, you will still need to bind the textfield element with some javascript events associated with it.
So, don't do such validations at server-side(Rails here), if you want such a high level of UI.

Comment: Agree about the UI element. Do you know if there's a gem for this? I'm sure the Char. count function is pretty common these days!

Comment: @ubique: Guess you didn't understand my answer well. Why do you want a gem for such a small thing, and secondly, gems are built in Ruby, so the validation will work at the server-side and not in the client browser, as I suggested.

Comment: The reason I was thinking a gem is because I want to stop the db accepting an article longer than say 500 chars on 'submit' (so probably a flash message) without the form clearing - as well as give the user a visual countdown for aesthetics....

Comment: @ubique: All this is very simple, and can be done with javscript. If you are having problems, on how to go ahead, google for it and you may find it easily

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that implements server-side validation and that will display a "flash" error message when validation fails.

In your Article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates_length_of :note, :maximum => 1000
  ...
end
```

In your ArticlesController:

```
  def create
    @article = Article.new
    if @article.update_attributes(params)
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
```

In your Articles view:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  // This can be moved to a template
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved:
    </h2>

    <ul>
      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  // More form fields
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but from the Users experience it would be too much hassle to keep the Char. count in their head!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do this in javascript, since it's client side functionality that you're looking for. You should also have model validations to ensure this limit is kept (you can get around javascript validations pretty easily by just sending a POST using something like curl).

Googling for "javascript character counter" gives plenty of results.

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice 'cross-browser' solution here via a jQuery plugin that will do the job and 'stop' users from submitting articles over the allocated amount on the client-side. [Here](http://roy-jin.appspot.com/jsp/textareaCounter.jsp) The required Rails plugin is [Here](http://mirror.ozdiy.com/assets/b8/2f96a12bc919b37e09d303b86ea1b9_1251811910.html)